# Merging features with same value in table (CSV)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, merge

I have a table (CSV) with statistical data for different neighbourhoods in a city (population according to different age categories).

My problem is that the neighbourhood doesn't have one field per category, but instead they have one row/feature per category in the table (i.e any given neighbourhood has 7 features/rows in the table).

I want to merge these features so each neighbourhood only has one row, to calculate child density. I can't figure out to do this when it's only a table, as the 'merge selected features' is disabled.

I have tried joining the table to a vector layer of the neighbourhoods but a lot of data is then lost.

How can I do this?

Example of what it looks like (not real data):

| id | Year | Neighbourhood_name | Category | Gender | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | Emilstorp | 0-5 years | Male | 15 |
| 2 | 2019 | Emilstorp | 6-15 years | Female | 25 |
| 3 | 2021 | Emilstorp | 0-5 years | Male | 20 |

And so it goes on. Each neighbourhood has at least seven rows/features, and sometimes from several years. I want all age categories to be in the same row for the year that I'm planning on using.

[image: Attribute table]

[image: Error message DB Manager]

---

I finally managed to fix my problem, using the Group Stats function.

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Sorry, QGIS (version 3.28.14-Firenze)

Comment: So you have your features of the neighbourhoods, e.g. "London Downtown", "Abbey Road", "The Wharf", etc., and you have "London Downtown Kids", "London Downtown Teens", "Abbey Road Kids", Abbey Road Teens", etc? As long as the neighbourhood names of features and table match, that should be a rather simple aggregate expression with a filter for the age category & neighbourhood.

Comment: Hi Klara H! Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Can you share example data? Just edit your post and paste raw CSV text data. It can also be dummy data that illustrates the issue. This would be very helpful in order to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your responses and the welcome :) I have added an example. @Erik Yes, kind of like that (see the example). Do you mean if they match features in a separate layer?

Comment: Research [Statistics by categories](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisstatisticsbycategories) or [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate)

Comment: do you want this kind of output? https://i.imgur.com/7jxzicj.png

Comment: Thanks @BERA I will check that out.

Comment: Yes, @aborruso, I want each row to have one field per age category with the neighborhood's respective values for the categories, instead of them being separate rows as they are now. The reason is that I want to add a field for child density in each neighbourhood

Comment: To be able to `aggregate` data using multiple attributes you can use the Aggragate processing algorithm.
Not having an example dataset available, I cannot go ahead with an example.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate

Comment: You have received many answers. None of them work? What problems have you had? If it works, choose the one you prefer

Comment: @aborruso thanks for your comments! I am trying the different suggestions I have received. So far it hasn't worked but haven't tried all of them yet. So far I have only tried the ones where I don't have to download additional things

Comment: Your query is missing commas

Comment: @pigreco I added commas and then the values were incorrect and many of them missing... I'm still working on it

Comment: Since you used the plugin suggested in my answer, why don't you select it as the correct answer for you?

Comment: @pigreco This is my first time using this forum, I didn't know there was an option to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using the [Group Stats](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) Plugin

using the data in the table attached to the question as input data.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I add also a simple SQL way, using the great [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/) cli.

Running

```bash
duckdb --csv -c "PIVOT (
  SELECT
    * EXCLUDE (id, Gender)
  FROM
    read_csv_auto('input.csv')
) ON Category USING SUM(Amount)" >output.csv
```

you get

```
Year,Neighbourhood_name,"0-5 years","6-15 years"
2019,Emilstorp,15,25
2021,Emilstorp,40,
```

I have used this input file:

```
id,Year,Neighbourhood_name,Category,Gender,Amount
1,2019,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Male,15
2,2019,Emilstorp,6-15 years,Female,25
3,2021,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Male,20
4,2021,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Female,20
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number of Categories are known and not too many (to type in manually in the query), you can create a query layer / virtual layer.

Open the DB Manager and execute the query in the Virtual Layers section.

My csv table is named `population`, with fields named `Year`, `Neighborhood_name`, `Category`, `Amount`. Add more case when rows for all categories:

```sql
SELECT row_number() over() as id,
    "Year", "Neighborhood_name", 
    CASE WHEN "Category" = '0-5 years' THEN sum("Amount") ELSE 0 END ages_0_to_5,
    CASE WHEN "Category" = '6-15 years' THEN sum("Amount") ELSE 0 END ages_6_to_15,
    CASE WHEN "Category" = '16-20 years' THEN sum("Amount") ELSE 0 END ages_16_to_20
    --Add more rows for each Category
FROM population
GROUP BY "Year", "Neighborhood_name"
ORDER BY "Neighborhood_name", "Year"
```

After you've loaded the table you can right-click and export it to file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use the DB manager but I get an error message.. I don't think I completely understand how I should tailor your example to my data. I tried pasting a picture here but couldn't. What does "row_number() over () as id" mean? Do I need to add something there? @BERA

Comment: yes, I did change the names to match mine, which is why it's so weird... The error message is "Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview as SELECT row_number() over as id, [..and then a copy of the whole query..] [...] GROUP BY "område": -1 near "CASE": syntax error"

Comment: I have added two screenshots of the query and error message + the table. I have now extracted the data from only 2022 so I don't have the year issue anymore

Comment: thanks! I didn't get the syntax error now. However, now the new table has a lot of missing values and where there are values, they're incorrect.. I don't know whats wrong now :/

Answer (score 1):

You could start from reshape the CSV.

If the input is in example this

```
id,Year,Neighbourhood_name,Category,Gender,Amount
1,2019,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Male,15
2,2019,Emilstorp,6-15 years,Female,25
3,2021,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Male,20
4,2021,Emilstorp,0-5 years,Female,20
```

Using the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/installing-miller/), you could run

```
mlrgo --csv cut -x -f id then \
stats1 -a sum -f Amount -g Year,"Neighbourhood_name",Category then \
reshape -s Category,Amount_sum then \
unsparsify input.csv >output.csv
```

to get

| Year | Neighbourhood_name | 0-5 years | 6-15 years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Emilstorp | 15 | 25 |
| 2021 | Emilstorp | 40 |  |

Some notes:

- `cut -x -f id` to remove the "id" field ([manual](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/reference-verbs/index.html#cut))
- `stats1 -a sum -f Amount -g Year,"Neighbourhood_name",Category` to sum the Amount grouping by Year, Neighbourhood_name and Category
- `reshape -s Category,Amount`, to reshape the table from long to wide ([manual](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/reference-verbs/index.html#reshape))
- `unsparsify` to have field names absent in a given record but present in others, fills in a value ([manual](https://field%20names%20absent%20in%20a%20given%20record%20but%20present%20in%20others,%20fills%20in%20a%20value))